# Figure out width of a String in a certain Font

Tags: java, android, string, fonts

Is there any way to figure out how many pixels wide a certain `String` in a certain `Font` is?

In my `Activity`, there are dynamic `String`s put on a `Button`. Sometimes, the `String` is too long and it's divided on two lines, what makes the `Button` look ugly. However, as I don't use a sort of a console `Font`, the single char-widths may vary. So it's not a help writing something like

```
String test = "someString";
if(someString.length()>/*someValue*/){
    // decrement Font size
}
```

because an "mmmmmmmm" is wider than "iiiiiiii".

Alternatively, is there a way in Android to fit a certain `String` on a single line, so the system "scales" the `Font` size automatically?

**EDIT:**

since the answer from wsanville was really nice, here's my code setting the font size dynamically:

```
private void setupButton(){
    Button button = new Button();
    button.setText(getButtonText()); // getButtonText() is a custom method which returns me a certain String
    Paint paint = button.getPaint();
    float t = 0;
    if(paint.measureText(button.getText().toString())>323.0){ //323.0 is the max width fitting in the button
    t = getAppropriateTextSize(button);
    button.setTextSize(t);
    }
}

private float getAppropriateTextSize(Button button){
    float textSize = 0;
    Paint paint = button.getPaint();
    textSize = paint.getTextSize();
    while(paint.measureText(button.getText().toString())>323.0){
        textSize -= 0.25;
        button.setTextSize(textSize);
    }
    return textSize;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [Paint.setTypeface(](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface%29)) and then [Paint.measureText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29). You'll find other methods on the `Paint` class like `setTextSize()` to help too.

Your followup question about scaling text was addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds).

Comment: thanks for the very useful hint, see my solution in the original answer